# Paparazzi: Can't get key animator_duration_scale from Setting.Global

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, screenshot

I've an issue with Paparazzi when I try to execute my screenshot test of my Composable item. The error that I get it's the following one:

```
Nov 25, 2022 10:53:52 AM app.cash.paparazzi.internal.PaparazziLogger logAndroidFramework
INFO: Settings [3]: Can't get key animator_duration_scale from content://settings/global
Nov 25, 2022 10:53:53 AM app.cash.paparazzi.internal.PaparazziLogger error
SEVERE: broken: View measure failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

1. I've used in the project gradle this classpath:

```
classpath ("app.cash.paparazzi:paparazzi-gradle-plugin:1.1.0")
```

2. In my module gradle I've imported as a plugin this:

```
plugins {
   ...
   id("app.cash.paparazzi")
}
```

3. My test:

```
class PaparazziExampleTest {

    @get:Rule
    var paparazzi = Paparazzi()

    @Test
    fun myComposableTest() {
        paparazzi.snapshot() {
            MyComposable("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

4. My composable:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(title: String) {
    Text(
        text = title,
        color = Brown,
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
        maxLines = 3,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code of your `MyComposable`? Or at least say if there are any side effects like calls to `LaunchedEffect`.  See potentially related [issue](https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi/issues/513).

Comment: I've just shared the code of `MyComposable`, but I don't have any sideEffects in this code yet.

Comment: Try resetting the LogManager: https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi/issues/1130